# Symfony2 mopa bootstrap bundle: form fields in the same line

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, symfony, twig

I'm using Mopa Bootstrap Bundle and I need to get two form fields to display in the same row.

In the rendered page I see that a div with class="form-group" is always added, and removing it when I need the fields aligned seems to be the way to go, but I can't find which options to give to $builder->add().

Any Ideas ?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Add `'horizontal' => false` to element options

```
$builder->add('element', 'text', array(
    'horizontal' => false,
));
```

It won't remove `form-group` div element, but will remove horizontal column layout.

Answer (score 0):

Answering that old question because i had the same problem and found it through google.

Setting it to horizontal isn't enough if you want to have it properly aligned in a bootstrap row, because additional margin is added by the form-group class.

You can remove it that way:

```
$builder->add('element', 'text', array(
    'horizontal'             => false,
    'widget_form_group_attr' => array(
        'class' => ''
    )
));
```

Comment: This may have worked in 2015 but fails with **The options "horizontal", "widget_form_group_attr" do not exist.** using Symfony 3.3.10 in 2017 :-(